# Multiple parameters in Angular.js 'when' call during routing

Tags: angularjs, model-view-controller, routes

Is it possible to pass multiple values into a '.when' call during routing? For example,

```
$routeProvider
    .when('/page1' || '/page2', 
    {

    });
```

Or would I have to call them individually like:

```
$routeProvider
    .when('/page1', 
    {

    })
    .when('/page2', 
    {

    });
```

I'm able to call them individually, but I want only a specific set of top-level pages. I'm wanting to know if I can bundle to save ~15 lines of extra code, or if I will have to call them individually.

Answer (score 1):

You can use named groups:

```
$routeProvider.
    when('/page:id'), {
        templateUrl: 'page-template.html',
        controller: 'PageCtrl'
    }).
    when('/404'), {
        templateUrl: '404.html',
        controller: 'NotFoundCtrl'
    }).
    otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/404'
    });
```

[http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute.$routeProvider](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute.%24routeProvider)

PageCtrl

```
app.controller('PageCtrl', function($routeParams, $location) {
    switch ($routeParams.id) {
    case 1:
    case 2:
    case 3:
    case 4:
        // code for your base pages
        break;
    default:
        $location.path('/404'); // not base pages, 404
        break;
    }
    // other code
});
```

In this way, if the url isn't one of `/page1`, `/page2`, `/page3` or `/page4`, the view will be redirected to 404 page.

Comment: Well, I have four base pages that I want to use a certain template, but I want to redirect the other top-level pages to a 404 or home page or something. So, if `:page` is `'page1'`, `'page2'`, `'page3'`, or `'page4'`, then go to those pages, but if `:page` isn't one of those, go to the 404. I can add the provisions individually, but I'm wondering if there's a way to group.

Comment: Hmm... that is a solution, but I'm really just curious as to if I can do it within the physical `.when()` call.

Comment: @Chad I don't think the bundled route module can do this at this moment.

Comment: @Chad Check this out https://github.com/gregorypratt/AngularDynamicRouting, he is trying to achieve even more dynamical routing.